# The code generates the same combination twice.How can I improve it?

Tags: java, logical-operators

The code is as follows:

```
package AG;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ArithmeticGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> number = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        permutateSigns('&', numbers, 0, "");
        permutateSigns('|', numbers, 0, "");

    }


    public static void permutateSigns(char operation, LinkedList<Integer> number, int pos, String expresion) {
        double sum = 0;
        if (pos == number.size()-1) {
            expresion += number.get(pos);
            System.out.println(expresion);
        } 
        else {
            expresion += (Integer.toString(number.get(pos)) + Character.toString(operation));
            permutateSigns('|', number, pos + 1, expresion);
            permutateSigns('&', number, pos + 1, expresion);
        }

    }
}
```

The output that I am getting from above code is :

```
1&2|3
1&2|3
1&2&3
1&2&3
1|2|3
1|2|3
1|2&3
1|2&3
```

How can  I get a combination only 1 time? I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that when `pos == number.size()-2`, you have a partial expression "1&2|".

Now, since `pos < number.size()-1`, you call:

```
permutateSigns('|', number, pos + 1, "1&2|");
```

and

```
permutateSigns('&', number, pos + 1, "1&2|");
```

Both will see that `pos == number.size()-1` and print the same expression - "1&2|3".

Conclusion:

When you reach the next to last element of your `List`, you should only make one recursive call to print the final expression.

Therefore, instead of:

```
        expresion += (Integer.toString(number.get(pos)) + Character.toString(operation));
        permutateSigns('|', number, pos + 1, expresion);
        permutateSigns('&', number, pos + 1, expresion);
```

you can write:

```
        expresion += (Integer.toString(number.get(pos)) + Character.toString(operation));
        permutateSigns('|', number, pos + 1, expresion);
        if (pos < number.size()-2) {
            permutateSigns('&', number, pos + 1, expresion);
        }
```

Following that fix, you'll get the output:

```
1&2|3
1&2&3
1|2|3
1|2&3
```